# Write custom nvram entry

Tags: linux, bios

As far as I understand, `/dev/nvram` contains the BIOS or UEFI configuration, which can be seen by reading `/proc/driver/nvram`. I was wondering if it is possible to write my own custom entry into nvram.

---

What I want to achieve:

I run Archlinux from a portable disk which I can use on my workstation, laptop, etc. I want to write an entry containing a number (or if possible a string) which allows my portable system to detect the computer it is being booted on, to for example load different configurations (e.g. graphics driver or multi monitor setup). I want the identification to be based on the mainboard.

Comment: I have no experience with this topic, but I think you will find this answer interesting: [efi variable entries in `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars/`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/418036/108618).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as I understand, /dev/nvram contains the BIOS or UEFI configuration, which can be seen by reading /proc/driver/nvram. I was wondering if it is possible to write my own custom entry into nvram.

The 'nvram' device actually provides the contents of the RTC (real-time clock) memory, which used to store BIOS settings in the earliest IBM PC days. The driver appears to be specific to BIOS systems only (not UEFI), and nowadays it has no relation to the actual NVRAM where the real settings are stored – the fixed 114-byte structure is a relic that's kept for compatibility with MS-DOS. While you can try writing to it, I wouldn't expect any additional information to remain.

Generally in BIOS systems, there's no other writable storage that would be accessible to the OS (unless you find something manufacturer-specific).

In UEFI systems, there *is* a general-purpose NVRAM which is accessible through "EFI variables", which Linux exposes through `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars`. You can create custom EFI variables and some programs already do so, e.g. you'll find a few variables created by systemd-boot. It might be better to use the `efivar` tool if you want to do this (there's also `efibootmgr` specifically for the Boot#### variables).

Capacity of the EFI NVRAM is limited, however, and some older PCs (around 5-6 years ago) could be bricked if the NVRAM was updated too many times.

> I run Archlinux from a portable disk which I can use on my workstation, laptop, etc. I want to write an entry containing a number (or if possible a string) which allows my portable system to detect the computer it is being booted on, to for example load different configurations (e.g. graphics driver or multi monitor setup). I want the identification to be based on the mainboard.

The traditional way is to use the MAC address of the device's built-in Ethernet port.

There *may* be a motherboard unique ID in the DMI information, available through `/sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/*`, usually in the `product_uuid` and `product_serial` attributes. (The `dmidecode` tool would show more.)

The graphics driver can be detected by looking at the actual graphics devices. (That's how both Windows and Linux already work – they load drivers based on the vendor:product IDs found by enumerating the PCI bus.)